# The following error occurred during the Herokuro react project build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, antd

[antd input bar code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2QE7.png) It occurred while using input bar in antd. What's the reason?

TypeScript error in /tmp/build_1442ffe6/node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts(16,11):
Type expected.  TS1110

```
       14 |     status?: InputStatus;
       15 |     bordered?: boolean;
     > 16 |     [key: `data-${string}`]: string;
          |           ^
       17 | }
       18 | declare const Input: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<InputProps & React.RefAttributes<InputRef>>;
       19 | export default Input;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem exactly yesterday, it was solved only by upgrading the `typescript` version to upper than 4.4, in my use case I used:

```
yarn add typescript@latest
```

P.S: I encountered a lot of typing issues while type compiling(build time), I solved them and after that, I could build successfully.