# How can I fix this input type error in antd design using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I upgraded antd v3 to v4, and my app doesnt run when I use yarn start. I use typescript.

I see the error:

```
TypeScript error in .../project_path/node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts(17,11):
Type expected.  TS1110

    15 |     status?: InputStatus;
    16 |     bordered?: boolean;
  > 17 |     [key: `data-${string}`]: string | undefined;
       |           ^
    18 | }
    19 | declare const Input: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<InputProps & React.RefAttributes<InputRef>>;
    20 | export default Input;
```

Can someone explain what this is, and how i can fix it? I am new to ts

Comment: Hi @merlin please check if this helps:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71655708/the-following-error-occurred-during-the-herokuro-react-project-build